# Реализация интерфейса

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Как можно проверить, реализует ли класс определенный интерфейс?

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под реализацией интерфейса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php)

```
interface MyInterface
{
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface
{
}

$a = new MyClass;

var_dump($a instanceof MyClass); // bool(true)
var_dump($a instanceof MyInterface); // bool(true)
```